# Crash when setting attributes dictionary of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have the following code:

```
UIFont * applicationBolFontOfSize26=[fontsSuperclass returnApplicationMainFontOfSize:26.0f];
[self.settingsButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : applicationBolFontOfSize26 } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where font superclass method is defined as:

```
+(UIFont *)returnApplicationMainFontOfSize:(CGFloat)floatSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Regular" size:floatSize];
}
```

but the `self.settingButton setTitleText...` crashes with error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Why?

Comment: well, something is nil... log or breakpoint your font before you assign it to the button.

Comment: yeah the font is nil, which is weird.

Comment: It is also easier to debug without compound statements, create the attributes in an intermediate variable. Then check each item for nil. Debugging skills are a part of writing software.

Comment: I shouldn't have to alloc init the superclass.

Comment: `fontsSuperclass` has to be created somewhere, show it.

Comment: Well it's a superclass, so it uses + methods.

Comment: No need to create an instance of it!

Comment: @louiskablooie What is `fontsSuperclass`? Is it a class name? If so by convention it should begin with a upper-case letter. Variables and methods begin with a lower-case letter. Since it begins with a lower-case letter it looks like and the assumption is that it is a method name.

Answer (score 4):

There is no font named "HelveticaNeue-Regular" so your font is `nil`.  Use `[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:floatSize]` for the regular Helvetica Neue font.

Comment: ah thank you, how would I specify Bold versus regular?

Comment: "HelveticaNeue-Bold" is the bold one.  You can see all of them by logging the value of `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica Neue"]`